# validate radio buttons for a quiz

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Need to validate radio buttons am developing a quiz page i can only validate 1 set of radio buttons any help be great below is my code. If a user hits the submit button without answering a question I want a alert message displayed saying u must answer whatever question they didnt answer. Any ideas as to why the jquery wont work thanks

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

                     <script type="text/javascript">
                     $('#quizForm').on('submit', function() {
    var emptyCount = 0;
    $('li').each(function() {
        var found = false;
        $(this).find('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                found = true;
            }
        });
        if (!found) {
            emptyCount++;
        }
    });
    if (emptyCount > 0) {
        alert('Missing checks:' + emptyCount);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
                     </script>


                  <form action='mail.php' method='post' id='quizForm' id='1' name='quizForm' onSubmit='form()'>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <h3>1 x 1 =</h3>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='A' />
                <label for='answerOneA'>A)1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerOne'  id='answerOne' value='B' />
                <label for='answerOneB'>B)2</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='C' />
                <label for='answerOneC'>C)3</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>1 x 6 =</h3>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='A' />
                <label for='answerTwoA'>A)5</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='B' />
                <label for='answerTwoB'>B)6</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='C' />
                <label for='answerTwoC'>C)4</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>2 x 8 =</h3>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='A' />
                <label for='answerThreeA'>A)14</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='B' />
                <label for='answerThreeB'>B)12</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='C' />
                <label for='answerThreeC'>C)16</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not code, this is just a wire-frame.

Comment: this is my html form??

Comment: Yes, but without any of the PHP code that actually makes things happen, we can't really help much.

Comment: after the formatting, now we can see it :)
@cincodenada: question is client side validation - based on the jquery tag - so it's becoming an appropriate question

Answer (score 3):

First: you should not have the same id multiple times on one page. So the id of each answer should be different.

Anyway you can go through all the `li` elements and check if there's a checked radio in it.

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var emptyCount = 0;
    $('li').each(function() {
        var found = false;
        $(this).find('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                found = true;
            }
        });
        if (!found) {
            emptyCount++;
        }
    });
    if (emptyCount > 0) {
        alert('Missing checks');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: It looks to me that none of the radio buttons even need an `id` — a `name` is sufficient.

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mvkk4/ Do you have jQuery working?

Comment: sorry am not that familar with jquery do u have to download it to get it workin???

Comment: Look for "jquery download". It's basically a javascript file which is also available hosted by google and jquery so you can choose to download it and serve it yourself or reference it from any hosted solutions

Answer (score 1):

Writing a custom validator for your code on here would probably just be excessive. I'd use bValidator and call it a day.

See their sections on "radio groups".

http://bojanmauser.from.hr/bvalidator/#groups